# How to open another App from my application (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

i Want to open another application Within my app when a button is pressed
Here is my Code

```
  public async void Button_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = "instagram://user?username=therock";
        string uri2 = "https://www.instagram.com/therock";
        string uri3 = "https://www.facebook.com/anyusername";
        string uri4 = "facebook://user?username=anyusername";
        var k = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync(uri);
        if (k)
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(uri3);
        }
```

My Question are

- Is my String Formatting correct for all of them, `uri4` I dont know the right format so i made this up
- what is the correct format for both a Facebook profile and Facebook page and also for instgram
- Is there a way to simplify my code

thx in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code

```
Launcher.OpenAsync("fb://profile/profile_id");
```

For twitter

```
Launcher.OpenAsync("twitter://user?user_id=userid");
```

For **page_id** right click on page and select view source page and find the page_id for facebook and same as for twitter find the **userid** .

Comment: `"fb://page/page_id"` Does this format work for pages and normal users or just for pages ?

Comment: Yes, you could have a try

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: it works fine with pages but doesn't work with normal users profiles

Comment: to open a profile page use `fb://profile/profile_id` edit your answer and i will accept it ,thx