# Launcher.Default.TryOpenAsync() not working in MAUI App

Tags: android, android-studio, maui, deep-linking, android-deep-link

When calling Launcher.Default.TryOpenAsync(), its always return false in MAUI app.
We need to open an installed app in our device from a button click. If not installed, it should go tor play store for download.

**Tried this code, but not working**

```
private async void Button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{   string package_name = txtPackagename.Text;   

    // bool supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("com.google.android.youtube") // not working...

    // Try to open You tube App installed.
    bool launcherOpened = await Launcher.Default.TryOpenAsync("com.google.android.youtube");

    if (launcherOpened)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Done", "Application Successfully Open.", "OK");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await DisplayAlert("No Support", ex.Message, "OK");
} 
}
```

Always its return false, even if the app is installed. How we can achieve this in MAUI?
In Android studio, we can open an app with a package name.

Android Studio Code(this code working in Android Studio Project)

```
public void openApplication(Context context, String packageN) {
Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageN);
if (i != null) {
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startActivity(i);
} else {
    try {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageN)));
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageN)));
    }
} }
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android#open-another-app).  You need to pass a url scheme, not a package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the package name of the app you want to open is `com.xamarin.secondapp`.

Then you need to add `IntentFilter` and `Exported =true` to `MainActivity.cs` of the app you want to open(`com.xamarin.secondapp`).

Just as follows:

```
  [Activity(Label = "SecondApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

**Note:** remember to add code `DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }`.

For the current app, you need to add `queries` tag for the app you want to open in file `manifest.xml`.

For example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.openappapp1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="OpenappApp1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">

      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


      <queries>
            <package android:name="com.xamarin.secondapp" />
      </queries>
</manifest>
```

And usage example:

```
public async void OpenSecondApp()
{

    var supportsUri = await Launcher.Default.CanOpenAsync("myapp://");
    if (supportsUri)
        await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("myapp://com.xamarin.secondapp");

}
```

Comment: thank you for the support. Adding DataSchemes  in the second APP(com.xamarin.secondapp) , is it possible to do like this : > 
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="myapp"
    android:host="com.sample.app"
    android:pathPrefix="/launch" />
  <!--note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>. 
I tried like this instead of DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }. But not working :(

Comment: Good thing is the variable supportsUri  is getting True :) . But the other app is not loading. got crashed at the load itself.

Comment: Do you want to add above code your shared to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file manually?

Comment: Why not add the `ActivityAttribute` I added on my answer to the `MainActivity.cs` of your app? We generally don't recommend adding these `ActivityAttributes` manually.

Comment: `But the other app is not loading. got crashed at the load itself. `  Could you please post the error log about this?

Comment: yes if its possible to add in manifest its better. pls..

Comment: I created 1 sample app and added the intent filter in manifest. (as mentioned in the previous comment). Then called that schema through Launcher.Default.TryOpenAsync uri. if the second app is Open in background then its launching as expected. if not, its throwing some error. but no details about the error.

Comment: You can debug your current app step-by-step to see what the problem is.

Comment: The other app not able to debug. how its possible..?

Comment: What I mean is that when you try to debug the first app, will there be some log messages when you try to open the second app?

Comment: No Jessie, no error in the first app. Its trying to load the second app and showing some black screen and suddenly it disappear. some times i am getting this message from the second app. > "Sample.Second.App is experiencing crashes. Please contact Sample.Second.App customer service for solution". This is what  i am getting :(

Comment: Yes, it is just the case as you said. If the second app that will be opened is in the background , its launching as expected. But if not, the first app could open the second app, but the second app is a blank page (mine is a blank page with a purple background).  And my second app is a maui app.

Comment: As a test, I created a form app as the second app, and the test result was that the second app was opened normally regardless of whether it was in the background or closed.

Comment: ok that cool... if u dont mind can u pls share both of that projects with me ?

Comment: For this problem, you can post a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose). Thank you very much for your feedback.  :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't allow uploading code on GitHub on this forum.

Comment: You can add the necessary code to your app I shared on my answer. And there is no other superfluous code.

Comment: understood :). Actually I was doubtful about how to add that IntentFilter in the second app. Now I understood how to  do that.. :)  and I did it, now its  working .... Thank you very much.

If we need to Open another app like Amazon, or Uber app,  or others app installed in our device, how we can get this DataSchema for those apps?

Comment: I haven't tried, but the implementation should be pretty much the same.  We need the package name of the app that will be opened. You can refer to thread: [How to open another App from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034794/how-to-open-another-app-from-my-application-xamarin-forms).

Comment: Thanks Jessie, From my App, I can able to open Amazon App with a URI. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Congrats. Happy coding... :)

Comment: Please have a look into this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402130/how-to-implement-swipe-buttonwith-events-in-maui-app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255823/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-msft-and-abhi).

Comment: Hi @Lessie, there is an issue with our approach. When we try to call the second app from a hyper link( <a href="myapp://com.xamarin.secondapp">Open Mobile App</a> ) , it wont work. If you already opened the app and running in the background then its loading.. but if not running background, it won't load when clicking  this type link. 
Anything I missed? dont know what is exactly happening..  Could you pls help ?

Comment: Didn't you say it was working properly? Has your code changed?

Comment: Hi Jessie, Its working perfectly when we call the second app from First app. But if I call the second app from a Hyper link, its not opening.

Comment: You can compare whether the parameter that passed into method `Launcher.Default.OpenAsync` is correct.

Comment: yes, I am passing the correct params....schema + host + Path Prifix. Its working when we call from MAUI APP. But I need to start it from a web ur and Hyper link.... how can I share the code ?

Comment: Hi,

instead of  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());  this code,  what is the equvalent code for MAUI app? ... the problem is when I click the hyper link, the app if displaying for a second.. suddenly its disappearing. so i think some issue with onCreate  ..

Comment: This should be an issue for Maui. You can create a new issue for Maui of GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Hi Jessie, What to do next with this? how we can trace it? can u pls try my code in ur side ? I will share it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255851/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-msft-and-abhi).

Comment: Hi @Jessie, I have a new ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575543/messagingcenter-send-is-not-triggering-messagingcenter-subscribe-method-in-mau

please have a look. its about MAUI.