# How to implement Swipe Button(with events) in MAUI App?

Tags: maui, swipe-gesture

How to imeplemnt swipe button with an event in MAUI app?
Looking for a button with an image or icon able to swipe left or right end.

**Attached sample image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the swipe button with an event in MAUI, you need to write a custom control that represents thumb and track-bar and also can invoke `SlideCompleted()` event when the slide action is completed.

Here's the demo for your reference:

1. Create a custom control: **MySlideView.cs**  that implements `AbsoluteLayout`:

```
   public class MySlideView : AbsoluteLayout
    {

        public View MyTrackBar
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(TrackBarProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TrackBarProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty TrackBarProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                "MyTrackBar", typeof(View), typeof(MySlideView),
                defaultValue: default(View));

        public View MyFillBar
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(FillBarProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FillBarProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty FillBarProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                "MyFillBar", typeof(View), typeof(MySlideView),
                defaultValue: default(View));

        public View MyThumb
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(ThumbProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ThumbProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ThumbProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           "MyThumb", typeof(View), typeof(MySlideView),
           defaultValue: default(View));

   
        private PanGestureRecognizer _panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        private View _gestureListener;
        public MySlideView()
        {
            _panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanGestureUpdated;
            SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;

            _gestureListener = new ContentView { BackgroundColor = Colors.White, Opacity = 0.05 };
            _gestureListener.GestureRecognizers.Add(_panGesture);
        }

        public event EventHandler SlideCompleted;

        private const double _fadeEffect = 0.5;
        private const uint _animLength = 50;
        async void OnPanGestureUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyThumb == null || MyTrackBar == null || MyFillBar == null)
                return;

            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Started:
                    await MyTrackBar.FadeTo(_fadeEffect, _animLength);
                    break;

                case GestureStatus.Running:
                   
                    var x = Math.Max(0, e.TotalX);
                    var y = Math.Max(0, e.TotalY);
                    if (x > (Width - MyThumb.Width))
                        x = (Width - MyThumb.Width);
                    if (y > (Height - MyThumb.Height)) y = (Height - MyThumb.Height);

                    MyThumb.TranslationX = x;
                    SetLayoutBounds((IView)MyFillBar, new Rect(0, 0, x + MyThumb.Width / 2, Height));
                    break;

                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    var posX = MyThumb.TranslationX;
                    SetLayoutBounds((IView)MyFillBar, new Rect(0, 0, 0, this.Height));

                   
                    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[]{
                    MyTrackBar.FadeTo(1, _animLength),
                    MyThumb.TranslateTo(0, 0, _animLength * 2, Easing.CubicIn),
                });

                    if (posX >= (Width - MyThumb.Width - 10/* keep some margin for error*/))
                        SlideCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Width == 0 || Height == 0)
                return;
            if (MyThumb == null || MyTrackBar == null || MyFillBar == null)
                return;


            Children.Clear();

            SetLayoutFlags((IView)MyTrackBar, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
            SetLayoutBounds((IView)MyTrackBar, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1));
            Children.Add(MyTrackBar);

            SetLayoutFlags((IView)MyFillBar, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
            SetLayoutBounds((IView)MyFillBar, new Rect(0, 0, 0, this.Height));
            Children.Add(MyFillBar);

            SetLayoutFlags((IView)MyThumb, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
            SetLayoutBounds((IView)MyThumb, new Rect(0, 0, this.Width / 5, this.Height));
            Children.Add(MyThumb);

            SetLayoutFlags((IView)_gestureListener, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
            SetLayoutBounds((IView)_gestureListener, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1));
            Children.Add(_gestureListener);

        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppSwipe"
             x:Class="MauiAppSwipe.MainPage">

 
   <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

        <local:MySlideView HeightRequest="60" SlideCompleted="SlideCompleted"  >
            <local:MySlideView.MyThumb>
                <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 60,60,60,60" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Padding="0" Margin="-20,0,0,0" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" x:Name="myframe" >
                    <Image x:Name="myimg" Source="dotnet_bot.png" Aspect="AspectFit"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" />
                </Border>
            </local:MySlideView.MyThumb>

            <local:MySlideView.MyTrackBar>
                <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 60,60,60,60" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" Padding="0">
                    <Label TextColor="White" Text="SWIPE TO ACTIVATE" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </Border>
            </local:MySlideView.MyTrackBar>

            <local:MySlideView.MyFillBar>
                <Border  StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 60,60,60,60" StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0,0,20,20" />
            </local:MySlideView.MyFillBar>
        </local:MySlideView>
      </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }



    private void SlideCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myframe.Margin= 20;
       //Raise SlideCompleted() event when the slide action is completed.
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alexandar for the solution. Its working as expected. only 2 thinks need to share with you.

1. how to make the icon visible always ? Now when we swipe the icon is displaying. Need to display the icon by default. I couldn't find any IsVisible property ... 
2. Is it possible to move the icon to the right ? now its showing a space between the icon and the right border. (at the end).

Comment: @Abhi Thanks for the update. 1. It seems that you need to swipe the icon firstly to make it visible. 2. It's possible to make the icon to the right without no space, add `myframe.Margin= 20;` , you can see my update.

Comment: HI @Alexandar, the second point, its fixed by adding the margin. for the first point, Showing the icon without touching the Bar, how can we implement a property like ShowImageIcon = true., something like that..? please advice...

And 1 more thin, if I want to make the 4 corners more rounded corners, 
where I can give the  radios? how I can achieve that .. pls advice...

Comment: @Abhi 1. For the round corners you want to achieve, you can set it as `Border` and then add `Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 60,60,60,60" StrokeThickness="0" `, I've updated to my answer, you can refer to it. 2. It looks like showing icon is a potential issue, I haven't figured out a way to bypass it, will update my answer if any solution for it.

Comment: thank you for the updates. I will try the same... Thank you very much.

Comment: @Abhi My pleasure, have a good day!

Comment: Hi @Alexandar, as we discussed about the custom control, can we keep the swipe button  at the end itself when we reached at the end? Now what is happening is, when we swipe the button, its moving to right side and once the event triggered, the swipe button is going back to the initial position, I mean the left side...  How we can we stop this ? 
Once it reached at the right side, let it be there... no need to go back to left side... Is it possible ? please have a look when u available.. Thanks

Comment: @Abhi That's another feature that you want to implement, you can ask a new question and I'll help you figure it out.

Comment: Sure, thanks Alexandar

Comment: Hi Alexandar, please see this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443858/maui-custom-swipe-control-with-left-right-swipe-directions

Comment: @Abhi Sure thing.