# MAUI Custom Swipe Control - With Left/Right Swipe Directions

Tags: mobile, maui, mobile-development, maui-community-toolkit

We already had a implementation of swipe button(thanks to [Alexandar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9644964/alexandar-may-msft) , [How to implement Swipe Button(with events) in MAUI App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402130/how-to-implement-swipe-buttonwith-events-in-maui-app/77415034?noredirect=1#comment136528221_77415034)).
Out of this, we need to implement some other functionalities:-

1. Right to Left swipe (need to set the direction of Swipe)
2. Color change while swipe(Need to apply different color of the background while swipe)
3. Keep the swipe button at the end(when swiping to the right/left side, button should be  placed at the end of the control, current implementation is not like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Color change while swipe(Need to apply different color of the
> background while swipe)

You can change the `Background` color of the track bar in the process of swiping the control:`GestureStatus.Running:`

```
case GestureStatus.Running:

   <!--Omitted for Brevity-->           
   MyTrackBar.Background = Colors.Green;
   break;
```

> Keep the swipe button at the end(when swiping to the right/left side,
> button should be placed at the end of the control, current
> implementation is not like that.)

If you want to the swipe button to reach at the end of the trackbar when finishing sliding it, you can set the first parameter: `x` of the method [TranslateTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.viewextensions.translateto?view=net-maui-7.0) when `GestureStatus.Completed:`

```
case GestureStatus.Completed:
  <!--Omitted for Brevity-->
                   
MyThumb.TranslateTo(MyFillBar.Width-MyThumb.Width/2, 0, _animLength * 2, Easing.CubicIn),
                });
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alexandar, 

Thank you for the updates. I will try the changes and let you know the feedback. once again thanks.

Comment: HI @Alexandar, Its working fine. Even though need to apply some enhancement. Because while swiping, its changing the color, but when we swipe back to the initial position, still the color is Green. And also the swipe is not in a smooth condition. 

2. As I mentioned before, Is it possible to show the Image at the begin or loading itself. Now when we  swipe, then only  the image and Text  is displaying. 
I need to display the Text and Image should show while loading the control. Thanks

Comment: @Abhi Yes, looks like the issue of showing the Image at the begin or loading itself only persists on Android, it works well on iOS.

Comment: Hi @Alexandar, the same is happening in your side as swell ? for Android. ? 
How we can trace it? Thanks

Comment: @Yes, I'm looking into it and to see if we can fix it.

Comment: Ok Alexandar. Pls let us know if any updates.

Comment: @Abhi Sure, if I found the solution for it, will provide you update.