# MessagingCenter.Send is not triggering MessagingCenter.Subscribe method

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

When calling the **MessagingCenter.Send** function from a button click, it's not triggering the **Subscribe** method in **MainActivity.cs**.
Need to call the DisplayMessage() in MainActivity.cs from the Button click of MainPage.xaml.cs. What is missing in this code ?

Below is the code which I used.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage{

 public MainPage()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
 }

 [Obsolete]
 private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MessagingCenter.Send<String>("user_name", "Message_text");
     // MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "Hi");
 }
}
```

**Subscribe in MainActivity.cs under Platforms\Android folder.**

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity{       

    //[Obsolete]
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
                    
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnCreate", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<String>(this, "Message_text", (value) =>
        {
            DisplayMessage(value);
        });

    }

    private void DisplayMessage(string value)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Message Text = " + value, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first argument of Send and Subscribe should be of the same type T.  Your Subscribe also expects a parameter but your Send does not pass one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

**MainActivity.cs**

```
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{

    public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Instance = this;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, int>(this, "PassedData", (obj, item) =>
        {
            DisplayMessage(item.ToString());
        });

    }


    private void DisplayMessage(string value)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Message Text = " + value, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

On `MainPage.xaml`,add a button to send message ,just as follows:

```
    private void OnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int>(this, "PassedData", 123);
    }
```

**Note:**

1.Please add your code into method

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

not method

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
                    
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    }
```

2.From [Publish and subscribe to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0), we know that `MessagingCenter` has been deprecated in .NET 7 and replaced with `WeakReferenceMessenger`. So, you can use [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) instead.

Comment: Thank you Jessie for the Answer. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Jessie, Its working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Please check this ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575931/how-to-check-an-app-is-installed-or-not-using-maui-app

Comment: Another colleague is working on your case.  :)