# How to check an App is installed or not using MAUI App?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit

Need to check one App is installed or not. Tried with below code, but its not working in .net MAUI App. Any alternate solution?

```
    [Obsolete]
    private bool isAppInstalled(String packageName)
    {

        PackageManager pm = this.PackageManager;

        bool installed = false;
        try
        {
            pm.GetPackageInfo(packageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
            installed = true;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            installed = false;
        }
        return installed;
    }
```

**Eg: trying to check Google Pay is installed or not:**

```
  Boolean result = isAppInstalled("com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user");
```

Its always return false, even if the app is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`<queries>` tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) for the app package you want check in the **\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest**. Such as:

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"/>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Hi Liyun, its working. Than you for your support.