# Why PackageManager GetInstalledApplications always triggering NotImplementedException?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-package-managers

I'm working on a C# Xamarin project where I need to get the list of installed apps from my android phone.

For this purpose I'm trying to use the method GetInstalledApplications from the PackageManager class.

Since the class is abstract, I can't use it directly. So I created a new class called PM2 that inherits all it's methods from it, including GetInstalledApplications.

Problem is when I try to use the method to get the List ApplicationInfo, it always triggers NotImplementedException, instead of returning the list.

Here's the code from the MyApp.Android\Services\HelperService.cs

```
        public IList<ApplicationInfo> PM()
    {
        IList<PackageInfo> lista = new List<PackageInfo>();
        PackageManager pm2 = new PM2();
        PackageInfoFlags flags = new PackageInfoFlags();
        IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = (IList<ApplicationInfo>)pm2.GetInstalledApplications(flags);
        return (IList<ApplicationInfo>)packages;
    }
```

This is the inheriting class with the inherited method. There are loads more methods but I just put in the relevant one:

```
[Obsolete]
public class PM2 : PackageManager
{
        public override IList<ApplicationInfo> GetInstalledApplications([GeneratedEnum] PackageInfoFlags flags)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

This is the interface through which I call the method outside the exclusively Android segment of the project. It's on MyApp\Services\IHelperService.cs:

```
public interface IHelperService {

    IList<ApplicationInfo> PM();
}
```

This is where I call the interface. It's on MyApp\Extensions\PaymentMethods.xaml.cs:

```
IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = DependencyService.Get<Services.IHelperService>().PM();
```

These are the permissions used on MyApp.Android\Properties\AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.RequestInstallPackages)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.QueryAllPackages)]
```

I need to get the apps list because my app(A) calls a third party app(B) and if app B isn't installed we don't want it to just throw an exception. We want to design a customize alert telling the user what he needs to do, namely, download app B.

Any help would be very much appreciated since I need this for work and it's been more than a month that I'm stuck with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familar with _Xamarin_, but _throw new NotImplementedException();_ always exists in new code, because you haven't replaced that line with the appropriate code yet.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, thank you. What should I replace it with in that case? Like I said, I'm trying to get the ApplicationInfo list to check for the installed applications.

Comment: As I previously stated, I'm not familar with _Xamarin_. But now that you know why the exception is thrown, you can perform some research on how to get the data that you're interested in.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought that once you inherited the class it would come with all it's properties and functions

Comment: You should not implement your own version of packagemanager nor create instance of it by yourself. You should obtain instance of it  from the Context

Comment: @Selvin How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as Selvin
said you can obtain instance of it from the Context if you want to use the `PackageManager`. Scuh as:

```
var packagemanager = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManage;
or
var packagemanager = Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager;
```

And then you said:

> I need to get the apps list because my app(A) calls a third party app(B) and if app B isn't installed we don't want it to just throw an exception

You can refer to this thread: [How to check an App is installed or not using MAUI App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575931/how-to-check-an-app-is-installed-or-not-using-maui-app/77576299#77576299). Use the [PackageManager.GetPackageInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags)) method is also a good choice.

Comment: It worked! I used the method from the How to check an App is installed or not using MAUI App link, but instead of PackageManager pm = this.PackageManager I used var pm = Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager on my HelperService.cs, then I added its equivalent interface on IHelperService.cs. I can not thank you enough!